# MYSQL Complex Update For Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a very complex table which is like this :-

```
Snos   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
1      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P1     6435200
2      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P1     234
3      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P1     6435
4      BD       AD2     C2      2010    P2     198448333
5      CD       AD3     C3      2011    P3     194414870
```

Now, I need to process a query that should duplicate a row where suppose p2,p3 or p1,p2 or even just p2 value is not available for that particular year or for from any of 2009 or 2010 or 2011 and put last column's value as zero in it.

So now my database should look like -

```
Snos   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
1      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P1     6435200
2      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P1     234
3      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P1     6435
4      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P2     0
5      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P2     0
6      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P2     0
7      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P3     0
8      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P3     0
9      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P3     0
10     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P2     198448333
11     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P2     0
12     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P2     0
13     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P1     0
14     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P1     0
15     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P1     0
16     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P3     0
17     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P3     0
18     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P3     0
19     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P3     194414870
20     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P3     0
21     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P3     0
22     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P1     0
23     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P1     0
24     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P1     0
25     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P2     0
26     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P2     0
27     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P2     0
```

I tried using temporary table like

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM table WHERE *Some Condition*;
    Some If Else
    Then
    UPDATE tmptable_1 SET Column6 = 0;
    INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

but its not working. Can any one help me.

Comment: What are unique constraint columns in this table.  example if you would check  AD voor 2012 in Column1 Column4 should have 2012 Column6 should have a 0 value the other Columns for year 2012 should have a duplication of the Columns from year 2011?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It should have 0 if the data is not available. Like there are cases where P1, P2 are available in column 5 , so it should insert p3 for all the years by duplicating rest value and having zero in the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the UNIQUE constraint is on  (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE your_table;

INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6)
SELECT t1.Column1,t2.Column2,t3.Column3,t4.Column4,t5.Column5, 0
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM your_table) as t1,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Column2 FROM your_table) as t2, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Column2 FROM your_table) as t2, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Column4 FROM your_table) as t4,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Column5 FROM your_table) as t5;

UPDATE tmp JOIN your_table ON
    tmp.Column1 = your_table.Column1
    tmp.Column2 = your_table.Column2 AND
    tmp.Column3 = your_table.Column3 AND
    tmp.Column4 = your_table.Column4 AND
    tmp.Column5 = your_table.Column5 AND
SET tmp.Column6 = your_table.Column6;
```

This should give you the desired result in the temp table, you can then truncate your_table and insert the data from temp.

You can also use a normal table instead of temp and swap them at the end.

Comment: This has taken my system down. It went into an infinite loop.
I have 12000 rows to work with....

Comment: I added select distinct to reduce the number of rows a bit, but you are asking for all possible combinations of the values of 5 fields...

Comment: shall i divide my database and den try..?? or is it because we used temporary table , this happened.?

Comment: Run `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Column1)*COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)*COUNT(DISTINCT Column3)*COUNT(DISTINCT Column4)*COUNT(DISTINCT Column5) FROM your_table`. That will give you the total row count of all combinations. If that is too much, you should probably rethink your approach. The temp table is capable of holding as many rows as a normal one would.

Comment: What should be the max possible value of that count.?

Comment: That's the number of rows of your final result. Querying that table will get slower as the row count increases. I might of missunderstood which combinations of rows you need, this will generate all possible combinations of all 5 rows.